# How to access methods of subclasses inside a list?

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have a parent class "bankAccount" with two subclasses and then those subclasses derive into other subclasses. I'm suppose to create a grandchildren object and save it inside a List, and then be able to interact with the methods of the grandchildren. However I can't seem to access the methods of these classes. All I can do is interact with the methods of the grandparent class.

This is how I'm adding a subclass to the List.

```
List<bankAccount> accounts = new List<bankAccount>();
accounts.Add(new VistaAccount(nAccount,pass,nameClient,balance,interest));
```

Comment: post the code for class declarations. are the methods public?

Comment: Yes, both constructor and methods of each class are public.

Answer (score 2):

First, understand why C# doesn't let you do that on a list of bank accounts.

If you have a list of all kinds of bank accounts, then whatever you do to *any* of them needs to be applicable to *every one* of them. You can't call a method on an object, unless that object is guaranteed to have that method. The static type system is there to warn you about that as early as possible.

That being said, if you really know you only have a handful of bank account kinds, you could maybe enumerate them separately:

```
foreach(var account in accounts.OfType<VistaAccount>())
{
    // call methods specific to "Vista" accounts
}

foreach(var account in accounts.OfType<OtherAccount>())
{
    // call methods specific to "Other" accounts
}
```

Now keep in mind that this kind of approach doesn't scale well in the long term. If more subtypes are introduced in the future, you may need to come back to that spot and add more special cases.

If there is a specific operation you want to perform on *every* account and the details of that operation happen to differ for each type of account, then there's a much better way to do it. Simply declare an abstract method on your base bank account type:

```
public abstract void Operation();
```

Then implement (`override`) that method in every kind of account, with instructions specific to that kind.

- This scales well in the long term, because you don't have to remember to introduce special cases whenever you introduce more account types. One less thing to document for your future self or the future maintainer of your code.
- It's more convenient, because if you ever forget to specify the operation for a subtype, you'll get a nice message at compile time. So there's a nice safety net in case you forget to do it.
- Because now every kind of bank account is guaranteed to support that operation, the compiler will happily allow you to make the call even on a list of bank accounts. You won't need the manual type checks that I proposed initially.

Comment: I intentionally did not explain casting or reflection because it's the question smells so much like trying to do the wrong thing for the wrong reasons, but I guess this way of doing it doesn't exist for no reason now so... +1

Answer (score 2):

Simply: what you want cannot be done and is actually wrong.

Advanced: what you want can be done using reflection or after casting but is still *very* wrong.

You can only use methods declared in your base class (`BankAccount`) on items inside the `list<BankAccount>`. If you need your grandchild objects to behave differently you should override methods (that must be virtual in your `BankAccount` class) in the grandchild classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access members of a child via the api of the parent. You need to have a reference to a type that exposes the member, either by casting (this is generally bad/ugly) or by defining a reference to be of the childs type to begin with.

If you really need a list of child objects, why are you using a list of parents? You need to reconsider the design of the current method if not more.

Answer (score 1):

This relates to the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/liskov-s-substitution-principle.html). You have a bunch of objects - some may be of type `VistaAccount`, others of different types, but they all inherit from `bankAccount`. By putting them in a `List<bankAccount>`, you're casting them all as the base class, `bankAccount`.

In that context the point is that you view all of them as `bankAccount` and it shouldn't matter at all whether some are `VistaAccount` or some other type. The only type that matters is `bankAccount`, and the subclasses don't matter.

If you're inspecting those individual instances to see what type they really are, chances are that that something is wrong. If you have to inspect each object to see what its type is, then the purpose is defeated. Taken to its logical conclusion, it could just be a `List<object>`.

What you want (if possible) is a design where the methods you call on each class are the same and only the behavior of those methods is different. For example, a `Circle`, `Square`, and `Triangle` could each inherit from `Shape`, and each one overrides the `Draw()` method. That method is different for each class. But if you put them all in a `List<Shape>` then you can call the `Draw()` method on each one without knowing which subclass each one is.